# Amplify shared user pool not working in one of two apps

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using a Cognito User Pool, for SAML integration with my corporate Azure AD directory. Everything has been set up and is working fine locally, as well as on both dev and prod environments associated with one of the apps.

However, when I tried to deploy another app with exactly the same code and configuration, the app works fine locally (i.e. I am able to log in using my corporate credentials) but the deployed sites do not work - both dev and prod keep returning the error `The user is not authenticated` when the following code is run:

```
        Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(currentUser => setUser(currentUser))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

One of the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60305200/4332644) in SO suggested that the user needs to be confirmed. There are two problems with that:

1. The account status is set to EXTERNAL_PROVIDER and cannot be altered, and
2. If the issue was with the user account (or the provider), the other instances (local as well as online) would also have thrown the error.

I configure the [callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67495188/4332644) as follows:

```
awsconfig.oauth.redirectSignIn = `${window.location.origin}/`;
awsconfig.oauth.redirectSignOut = `${window.location.origin}/`;

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

And I trigger the login using the following code, based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67570221/4332644):

```
<button onClick={() => Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: '<My corp provider string>'})}>
```

Again, the same code is working fine locally (though still using the same user pool).

Any idea why the user is not being considered authenticated for just these two environments? Any help is appreciated.